# Customizable and interactive map

Tags: javascript, maps, markers

I have a kinda silly problem. I'm having troubles with creating a custom map (similar to what you can do with Google My Maps) but with an additional ability of interacting with it programatically.

I have read about google my maps not having an API which is making my life difficult.

I need to change map location and the markers that go along with each location based on user input.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,
Djordje

EDIT:

I don't need anyone to code a solution for me, just an information as to which Library I could use to achieve my goal. So far, I have tried Google my maps and it's extremely easy to add markers and embed it onto the page, but from what I gathered from my research it's not possible to interact with it via API.

What I need is a library that would allow me to create custom markers and then change the display portion of the map to the selected city.

Comment: So what have you tried so far? Are you having a problem with a specific part of your code? We aren't here to create it so if you have specific issues please let us know. We would be generally more than happy to help fix any unique issues. But just saying you need this and that is bad. Essentially see this for why this question is currently not a question: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/126721790)

Comment: Hey, it is not a specific issue. I just need a nudge in the right direction. I don't need anyone to "create code" for me, just to tell me what technology/library I could use for this. 

I was thinking to do it through Google My Maps and that's what I tried, it's easy to embed it on the page but it's not possible to interact with it (display a different area based on user input) 

Thanks for answering though, I'll edit the question above.

Comment: Even that is off-topic. Asking for suggestions about what libraries is off-topic for SO and will be flagged as such. Please read [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer for anyone needing to do the same thing as me.

The answer is Google maps javascript API + KML Layer, which is something you can obtain from Google My Maps. Inside the KML layer is located information about the previous generated custom markers.

For interactivity and changing the map based on input, you can proceed to use the Google Maps Javascript API.

Also, remember to host the KML file elsewhere so that the google api can access it.

```
<style>
  #map{width:600px;height:600px}
</style>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
let src = "https://host-host.com/webs.kml"
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 11,
    center: {lat: 44.05588, lng: 21.03553}
  });

  var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: src,
    map: map
  });
}

</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={API_KEY}&amp;callback=initMap">
```

And remember to add the google API script after the code so that the callback "initMap" could be executed.